# Which NPCs are considered hostiles, and which are considered civilians? Also, does killing a civilian add more chaos compared to killing a hostile?

Tags: dishonored

At the end of a mission, the mission stats will state how many 'hostiles', and how many 'civilians' you killed.

Which NPCs are considered hostiles, and which are considered civilians? Is there any easy way to know if an NPC is considered a hostile or a civilian? Also, does killing a civilian add more to chaos, compared to killing a hostile?

Instances where it is unclear whether an NPC is a hostile or a civilian:

- Thugs at the [Distillery](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Dunwall_Whiskey_Distillery), in the [House of Pleasure](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/House_of_Pleasure) mission

  > (where they don't attack unless provoked)
- [Lord Shaw](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Montgomery_Shaw) at the [Lady Boyle's Last Party](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Lady_Boyle's_Last_Party) mission

  > He will fight you in a duel, if you do an optional mission objective.
- The [Scavenger](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/The_Royal_Physician#Side_objectives) at the [Royal Physican](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/The_Royal_Physician) mission
- [Granny Rags](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Vera_Moray) at the [Flooded District](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/The_Flooded_District) mission

  > She'll fight you if you choose to do an optional mission objective.
- [Samuel](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Samuel_Beechworth)

  > who [will alert guards to your location if playing at a  'very high chaos'](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/89791/4797) at [The Light at the End](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/The_Light_at_the_End) mission.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down - comments are nice.  Personally, I have the same problem.  After I stopped murdering everyone, I went through the Flooded District and after the fact it was said that I murdered a civilian, even though the only 'person' I killed was Granny Rags.

Comment: To the downvoter(s): please comment why you downvoted this question so I would know what was wrong with it. This is so I could address that concern or edit the question to improve it.

Comment: Regarding Lord Shaw, you can shoot him with a sleeping dart and get credit for that mission while not killing anybody. I remember reading that a kill is a kill is a kill. I think they both add the same to your chaos meter. Sorry I don't have a reference.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that Lord Shaw is considered a hostile, and not a civilian. [In this mission's stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFu1H.jpg), I killed Lord Shaw, but it still stated zero civilians killed.

Comment: This is a partial answer to my question. If anyone knows of more details, please feel free to post another answer.