# Are there benefits for achieving max chaos?

Tags: dishonored

I was playing Dishonored and for now, it seems to encourage stealth.  Is there a benefit of going for max chaos? ie. killing anyone I see and making evil choices. Are there unique items?  Quests dialogs? Anything at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually a significant difference in how a certain character will behave (and how [a certain mission](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/The_Light_at_the_End) could be played) between high chaos, and *very high* or max chaos (not shown in the ending):

> I just finished a 3rd playthrough where I went lethal+stealthy. As a
>  result, I had a moderate number of kills - the first few missions said
>  I had Low chaos, but it had changed to High by the time I got to the
>  last mission, since I went on a bit of a rampage with the assassins.
>  On "very high" chaos, Samuel is a total dick to you and warns guards
>  by firing into the air. On my playthrough, he simply said he was
>  disappointed by how "brutal" I had become, and drove the boat away in
>  silence.

<sup>Source: [Reddit /r/dishonored: "There IS a difference between "high" chaos and "very high" chaos, just not in the ending"](http://www.reddit.com/r/dishonored/comments/11rhtw/there_is_a_difference_between_high_chaos_and_very/)</sup>

> If you have been extremely violent in your playthrough, Samuel will even fire a gunshot to warn the guards on the isle.

<sup>Source: http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/The_Light_at_the_End#Trivia</sup>

Comment: There's also a precious achievement for a high-chaos ending, and several achievements you can only get while killing people.

Answer (score 3):

If you play with Very High Chaos and you keep up your bloody sci-fi massacre streak until the end of the game, you'll get a different ending.  Check out [this thread for details](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87372/why-shouldnt-i-murder-all-the-things?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you consider a darker atmosphere a benefit then yes, but essentially the game will be harder because of increased weepers and more plague rats. A lot of people consider the chaos system a [punishment](http://penny-arcade.com/2012/10/10), not a choice.

Answer (score 0):

Lke the above three mentioned creating chaos causes "ill"effects in latter missions, unless you want more weepers to kill. it also changes something in the end:

> the picture emily draws of you: rather than it saying daddy with hears it shows you on a pile of corpses with your mask on. the game is meant to be a simulation i.e. cause an effect