# Does using Shadow Kill lower your chaos level?

Tags: dishonored

I've read that killing more NPCs and leaving the bodies in plain sight increases your overall chaos level.  Since Shadow kill leaves no bodies behind (at max level), does that lower your chaos score?  Reading around the net I can't seem to find a straight answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. As far as chaos is concerned, kills are kills, so long as it happens by your hand.

(Now luring guards and weepers into conflicts with each other, that's fair game.)

Comment: Based on this, is it safe to assume the silent takedowns are non-Chaos boosting as well?

Comment: @Fluttershy if you mean non-lethal, yes.  However, you must mind the bodies; if they get eaten by rats or such, they'll count.  See here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87258/whats-the-best-strategy-to-keep-the-chaos-low/87268#87268

Comment: well crap.  .   ,,,,

Answer (score 2):

You will still get chaos from the kills.
However kills are not the only source of chaos, found unconscious or dead bodies generate chaos too.
As this skill makes dead bodies disappear, it will definitely help lower the chaos, if you are playing lethal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to kill and still would like to see good ending **shadow kill is a right answer**.

I sneaked through the first mission (until you get your powers) and then killed everyone (except mission targets - for those I went non-lethal way. Yes I even spared Daud) and still got the happy "golden age" ending.

**As long as you keep your kills stealthy** and no one sees you kill or sees  the disappearing body of an enemy (if you shoot him with crossbow) you get low chaos and Ghost each mission. The only thing you will miss from pacifist gameplay is dealing with snoring unconscious bodies and "never killed anybody" achievement.

For the Low chaos I would recommend you to keep SK on first level. That way if the body doesn't disappear you know you screwed up :D