# When people turn to ash does it count as a body?

Tags: dishonored

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does using Shadow Kill lower your chaos level?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87428/does-using-shadow-kill-lower-your-chaos-level)

In Dishonored the skill shadow kill will turn enemies to ash if you kill them when they are unaware of you (or all kills if you upgrade the skill). The game states multiple times that the more bodies you leave around the more chaotic the city and the darker the ending. Does killing an enemy contribute to the body count/darker enemy if they turn to ash?