# Does shadow kill increase amount of plague in the city?

Tags: dishonored

So I have been reading some Q/A here on gaming.stackexchange for dishonored and in the middle of it I thought to myself "Does shadow killing increase the amount of weepers, rats and overall plague in the city?" The reason I thought this is because if the dead bodies turn to ash then there is nothing for the rats to feast on and no disease to spread.

Side question: Does killing weepers decrease the amount of plague?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The amount of weepers and rats in the city is determined by your [Chaos level](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Chaos).

Chaos level is determined by [how many people you murder, and Shadow Kill is considered murder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87428/does-using-shadow-kill-lower-your-chaos-level).  So is killing weepers.

Thus, killing with Shadow Kill will increase the amount of plague-related stuff you encounter in the game, and can increase your chances of getting the "High Chaos" ending.

Comment: So basically, the only advantage Shadow Kill has is negating the need to dispose of bodies properly

Comment: @BakedPotato, pretty much, yeah :(

Comment: Damn, well at least my logic made sense....