# Killing animals in Dishonored: will that ruin achievements?

Tags: achievements, dishonored

Can I kill animals, such as the dogs, and still get the achievements?  I'm looking at one achievement that says I can kill "no one".  I'm not sure if that includes the animals or not.

Comment: I know that Hagfish and Rats are a nonissue. Dogs... I'm not so sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best strategy to keep the chaos low?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87258/whats-the-best-strategy-to-keep-the-chaos-low)

Comment: @SteveV. I don't think this is a duplicate as this question is asking about how killing animals will affect achievements, while the [other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87258/whats-the-best-strategy-to-keep-the-chaos-low) is not about achievements at all.

Comment: @galacticninja - Achievements no, killing yes.  That's why I dupe'd it.

Comment: @SteveV. But that's the point. Keeping chaos low isn't necessarily related to gaining several of the achievements...in particular the one that says that the player can't kill anyone: someone looking at that goal isn't wondering how to keep chaos low...they're wondering how to get the achievement. The goal is different, and presumably the person searching is looking for a different reason. The answers are similar, but not the questions.

Comment: @SteveV. To add to Beska's point above, the other question is about how to keep the chaos low, not asking about 'killing' specifically. (Also, [killing is not the only thing that affects chaos.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/90107/4797))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the ["Notes on Stealth Detection, Chaos, and Trophies/Achievements" post in the Bethesda forums by *Gstaff*](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1415445-notes-on-stealth-detection-chaos-and-trophiesachievements/), a Community Manager at Bethesda:

> #### How does the Chaos system work? How do I raise or lower the Chaos level that is displayed on the end mission stats screen?
>
> - Rats, Hagfish and River Krust do not raise Chaos if killed. They also do not count towards detection of your character.
> - Wolfhound kills do not count towards Chaos, but they can detect your character and will count towards that. They can also discover
>   bodies, as well as their corpse will count towards “bodies found”.

Note that by "*does not raise or count towards Chaos*", it is also meant that they will not count as a kill. This is because [the more you kill NPCs, including Weepers, the more you increase Chaos](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/90107/4797).

Answer (score 5):

Well, I went ahead and killed some of the hounds...and I still got the checkmark at the end reading "Didn't kill anyone".  So my strong suspicion is that the hounds don't count for the achievement, either.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87258/whats-the-best-strategy-to-keep-the-chaos-low) killing animals does not count against you. Except weepers, if you consider them animals.