# How do I prevent rats from eating a corpse that I left unattended? Also, is this a bad thing?

Tags: dishonored

I was on my way to a mission objective, when I was suddenly jumped by assassins. Luckily, [a couple of friendly thugs helped me kill them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AA2E.jpg).

After I killed them all, I dumped their bodies in the same, nearby location (near where the thugs are). I did one of my mission's objectives, and when I came back, the bodies (or body, rather, as only a single corpse was left) are now this:
[image: rat devoured corpse]

Is this a bad thing? Do rat-eaten corpses have an additional effect on Chaos levels or other effects on the game (compared to if the corpses didn't get eaten)?

How do I prevent rats from eating a corpse? (Where should I leave the corpses?) Also, are unconscious bodies also vulnerable to being eaten by rats?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unconscious bodies *are* vulnerable to being eaten by rats.  You can store them in garbage bins to make them completely safe.  The same holds true of corpses.  There is also an ability that turns corpses you kill (level 1: stealth kills only, level 2, both) to ash, making it a non issue.

A kill is a kill where Chaos levels are concerned.  Tucking the bodies away/disposing of them helps prevent you being detected in mission, but if they are actual corpses they're going to contribute to potential chaos level increase regardless.

Comment: Just to clarify: So, a corpse eaten by rats won't give an *additional* effect on Chaos levels (compared to a non-rat eaten corpse)?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, no.  There is a good link in this answer:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87258/whats-the-best-strategy-to-keep-the-chaos-low that doesn't make any such distinction.

Comment: Since a couple people downvoted my answer because this answer already said it, I've deleted that, and am saying it here instead, so they can be right: it's a bad thing if you are trying for a no-kills run-through and have left someone unconscious. Rats can kill and eat them when they are unconscious, and this will count as a kill against you, and break your achievement (just like any other source of accidental death, eg drowning, falling, area effect, traps, splash damage, mob attacks...).

Answer (score 4):

If there's no garbage bins around, try putting the bodies out of reach of rats that might spawn - small tables are probably best so that the rats would be unlikely to spawn on the small surface area of the table. If you're trying not to kill many people at all, rats will be quite rare anyway.

Comment: Can rats climb onto tables?

Comment: Nope. They can't climb anything but ramps and stairs - i.e. rats can't jump (especially the white ones).

Comment: @tomeoftom - I read this comment three times before I got the joke