# Do I need to stash unconscious Weeper bodies to save them from rats?

Tags: dishonored

Related: [How do I prevent rats from eating a corpse that I left unattended? Also, is this a bad thing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/87725/5398)

I have been playing compassionately and I know that when rats devour a body it counts as a kill against you, so I've taken the time to stash bodies in places that rat swarms can't get to.

I just knocked a Weeper unconscious.  I know from the hints during the loading menu that summoned rats won't attack a Weeper, due to the advanced progress of the plague.

**Does this mean I don't have to worry about rats devouring the bodies of Weepers I've knocked unconscious?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should stash unconscious Weepers, if you really want to make sure that they won't be eaten by rats. (Good hiding places are described in [the answers to this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/87725/4797).)

I did some testing with the [Devouring Swarm](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Devouring_Swarm) power, which spawns a swarm of rats (those rat swarms behave just like normal rat swarms):

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

Comment: Another victory for SCIENCE

Answer (score 4):

The rats will eat anything unconcious including weepers if you have summoned the rats using devouring swarm. Normal rats not summoned by Corvo will not touch weepers concious or unconcious.

Answer (score 0):

The rats should not attack the weeper because they are still considered living by the game. However it is rare to find any rat swarms around weepers in general.

Comment: I'm not sure if I believe this...if that's true that they're still considered living, wouldn't that mean that unconscious non-infected humans would be safe from rats too?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. Why would non-infected humans not be attacked? The rats avoid the weepers because of their plague condition not the fact that they are alive.

Comment: Then why did the rats eat the unconscious Weeper bodies in the screenshots in galacticninja's answer?