# How many rats does it take to get to the center of a corpse-pop?

Tags: dishonored

I'm starting a ghost/non-lethal run of Dishonored and I know I need to avoid [rats eating my victims](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87725/how-do-i-prevent-rats-from-eating-a-corpse-that-i-left-unattended-also-is-this). I've noticed that single rats do not *appear* to go after corpses, but big swarms definitely do. So how many rats is enough to start eating corpses? I've noticed they only seem to eat corpses in "swarms" that will also attack the player.

<del>But leaving a single or just a couple rats alive around bodies is okay...right?</del> from further experience it appears that, rarely, randomly spawned rats may be enough to kill unconscious people! I found four rats in the general area of a dead guy, however I'm not 100% sure the rats killed him, as his corpse wasn't eaten to the bone, and I didn't see the rats attack him. It'd be extra useful to know whether or not randomly spawned rats will spawn in great enough numbers to kill an unconscious person.

Comment: I've never made it without Blinking...

Comment: I always elevate the bodies, just to be sure.

Comment: Hm, I left someone in a bush and found them dead (but not chewed to bits) with 4 rats nearby later. I'm unsure if the rats actually killed him though.

Comment: Yeah, but the rats also random spawn, i stunned a guy on the floor and i walked the wrong way. Out of no where some rats spawned so i had to go run faster then them pick up the guy and dump him in a dumpster.

Comment: @Lyrion they're randomly spawned? That's good to know

Comment: I think it's something around 8, but I've uninstalled the game a while ago, so I can't check. You could probably test it fairly easily with some save scumming by tossing an unconscious guard at a pack of rats, taking note of their number, then reloading, killing half the rats, and tossing the guard in again. Repeat until you find X.
Keep in mind that unconscious characters die if they fall a certain distance or touch water. A couple of rats is usually not a problem, and I haven't seen small groups spontaneously grow into an aggressive swarm.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann good idea. I've been killing all the rat swarms I see so I hadn't even thought of that

Answer (score 1):

The number of rats is irrelevant. All you need to make sure is that the body cannot be eaten. In that regard, Steve V. is right, the best practice is to elevate the body or put it in a garbage, ... You get the idea.

Be careful though, as you can easily kill someone without paying attention. I already kill a man just by trying to drop the body on the ground. His head knock the wall and he was dead. Or the best: I failed a blink and fallen on a guy I just dropped on the ground a little earlier. Apparently it was from too high because he died... So frustrating.

Anyway, just remember, don't care about the number of rats, just pay attention to where you drop the body: if they cannot touch the body, they'll never eat it.

Good luck for your achievements, I know how good it felt when I got mine ;)