# Do unconcious people who fall in water die?

Tags: dishonored

I have successfully performed a non-lethal take down, but the body fell into the water.  If I am going for one of the no kills achievements, do I need to worry about them drowning?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes, if an unconscious body falls into water, it counts as a death, and the blood is on your hands.**

If you go back down to collect the body, you should see the dead symbol rather than the sleep symbol. If you're on the bridge level or one of the other places where this is impractical, you may want to reload from a previous save just to be safe.

See here for a comprehensive list by galacticninja of everything that counts as a kill against you: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/90107/5398

Comment: Do they die instantly or do I have time to get them out of the water?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - Good question. I *think* they die instantly, but it would be worth testing out.

Comment: They die instantly, as do conscious guards. You are the only person in an entire island city that can swim.

Comment: At least in Thief they didn't croak for 30 seconds or so.

Comment: Aw crap, I always thought that water is a good place to hide unconscious people, not corpses. Now I know why I didn't get that achievement thingy! Thanks for that valuable information.

Comment: Why would you hide an unconscious person under water? You know they drown, right?

Comment: Achivement unlocked: "One born every minute"