# Is there a limit on the number of bodies/corpses/lockboxes in a certain zone? How do I increase this limit?

Tags: pc, bioshock, bioshock-2

I would like to know if BioShock 1 or 2 limits the number of bodies/corpses in a certain zone ([like Dishonored](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/89009/4797), another game that also uses the Unreal engine). Does either game remove corpses to make way for new ones?

**If the game(s) do have this limit, how do I increase this limit in the PC version of the games?**

EDIT:

I noticed that some of the corpses magically turn into [lockboxes](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Lockbox) in BioShock 2.

How does the corpse conversion into lockboxes work? At what point will the game start turning corpses into lockboxes? Does the game have a limit on the number of lockboxes at any given time?

Comment: afaik, Bioshock1-2 vanished bodies when your system was too much under pressure (ie during adam gathering rumbles), but i don't exactly know if there's some sort of soft/hard cap on bodies on the floor

Answer (score 2):

I remember in a specific sequence when I had to guard the Little Sister for a while, about 10-20 splicers came through and most of them turned into lockboxes over time. The PC I played the game on at the time was above the system requirements and would have no problem with the multiple corpses, so I doubt it's *actually* optimised per-system.

However, I *do* know the Havok physics engine BioShock 1 & 2 use [is locked at 30fps, regardless of your own framerate](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2-xGY75084), possibly due to the fact the 360 version is locked at 30fps. It's possible this "disappearing corpses" thing was done to prevent excessive load on the physics engine on the 360, and remained in the PC version, like the physics framerate cap.

Comment: Do you know how to configure the PC version of the game to remove the corpse limit? Kinda like in [Dishonored here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/89009/4797) (which also uses the Unreal engine)