# Is there a maximum limit on the amount of corpses I can pile up? How does it work and how can I remove/increase the limit?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

<sup>[Related.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04F4xlWSFh0)</sup>
I would like to know if BioShock Infinite limits the number of corpses in a certain zone (like the [previous BioShock games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/101821/4797) and [Dishonored](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/89009/4797), other games that also use the [Unreal Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_Engine)).

I also noticed that like the previous BioShock games, some corpses are also magically turned into lockboxes:

[image: Where the hell did these lock boxes come from?]

- Does the game remove corpses or lockboxes to make way for new ones? How does it work?
- What if I haven't looted the body or lockbox yet? Will the corpse or lockbox still be removed?
- How does the corpse conversion into lockboxes work?
- If the game does have a corpse or lockbox limit, how do I increase this limit in the PC version of the game? I prefer removing or increasing the corpse limit and see less or no lock boxes at all. (The lockboxes break immersion, I mean - Where the heck did those lockboxes come from?)

Comment: I've noticed that lockboxes appear if the corpse disintegrates (dying under the effects of the Shock Jockey vigor is one way this can happen), and only if that corpse had loot. I don't know of any other circumstances that a corpse can be converted to a lockbox, and, having played later-game, I doubt that there are any. I don't know anything at all about corpse limit though.

Comment: @Unionhawk A lockbox appears only if a corpse is lootable but no longer visible, either because it was disintegrated, or removed by the engine. The engine automatically removes corpses after some time has passed, or the limit of visible corpses was reached. Don't know about any limit to lockboxes, though.

Answer (score 6):

There is certainly a limit to the number of corpses/lockboxes in an area.  I am not aware of any way to increase this limit.

Corpses will automatically decay (regardless of method of death, although disintegration tends to produce a lockbox immediately) over time into lockboxes.  The older corpses/boxes seem to disappear to make way for the newer ones, in my experience.  They will disappear without having been looted.

The easiest place to test this is the combat sequence at the Good Time Club.  It's a long engagement in a relatively small area, and there are a lot of enemies, with breaks between waves to explore a bit.

The first wave here has a Fireman enemy, and I didn't have time to go loot his corpse between waves.  By the time I'd cleared the next wave of enemies, the corpse and lockbox had despawned.  There were also several enemies that I took down at a distance whose bodies had disappeared by the time I had a chance to go to where they'd died.

Enemies also drop their weapons separately from their corpse/lockbox.  These tend to despawn somewhat slower, but they will still despawn over time.

The "bigger" bad guys tend to drop better loot - things like 80% health kits and the like.  If you have a moment, it pays to loot these guys ASAP.

There appears to be a limited amount of persistence when changing zones.  Sometimes I can exit an area and then turn around and come back and still find some stuff lying around, but it tends to disappear quickly.  There are also times when zones you've been to before change or are restocked with enemies, and this seems to reset/remove any corpses or lockboxes.