# Do warhound bodies found count towards chaos?

Tags: dishonored

If you kill a hound (and no one sees you do it), yet they see the dead hound's body, does this raise chaos? I understand that killing it does not, but I am not sure if say a guard sees a dead wolfhound will affect your chaos level. (I REMAIN UNDETECTED THROUGHOUT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wolfhound kills do not count towards Chaos, but they can detect your
>   character and will count towards that. They can also discover bodies,
>   as well as their corpse will count towards “bodies found”.

<sup>Source: Bethesda Dishonored forums post, "[Notes on Stealth Detection, Chaos, and Trophies/Achievements](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1415445-notes-on-stealth-detection-chaos-and-trophiesachievements/)" by Gstaff, a Community Manager at Bethesda Softworks</sup>
For more info on Chaos mechanics, see this question: [What's the best strategy to keep the chaos low?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/87258/4797)

Comment: Ah yes. I just decided to look that up now. Silly me. Thank you very much :).